# Identify the active item in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Given a worksheet, I understand that `selected items` and `the active item` are not the same thing. It seems that only one item of all the selected items can be active. I would like to write a piece of code to identify `the active item` automatically.

`Selection` always refers to `selected items`, however it seems that there is no expression like that to fetch `the active item`. The types of the active item can be various. It may be a cell, in this case `ActiveCell` is used to refer to it. It also can be a `Chart`, then `ActiveChart` should be used.

Do I have to check all the `ActiveXXXX` to get the active item? In this case, is there an exhaustive list for this?

Otherwise, does anyone know any other workaround?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why you should avoid using `Selection` and `Activate` methods... you probably already know this, but just in case you do not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select

Comment: Well, I am not using them... I just want to parse/identify them...

Comment: @DavidZemens You're right, there are lots of reasons to not use Selection & Activate, but what if I want to kick the focus to a certain cell or range when a certain action happens? There are legit reasons to use `.select` and `.selection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the below should cover most situations. **I only have come across these from experience so there could certainly be ones I have missed**. However, it is important you understand what the Selection is - as intepreting what is the 'Active' item is pretty subjective.

- In terms of actual "Active" items there is only ActiveCell and
  ActiveChart that relate to Selection. ActiveWindow/Dialog/Workbook/Sheet etc are never in Selection. The others below infer what the 'Active' item should be and is dependent on your taste.
- For example, a selection of multiple shapes (or controls etc) is contained within DrawingObjects.ShapeRange. There **is** no active item so it is up to you to decide how to treat that. The below returns the first item (which I think is the item first selected by the user).
- Similarly, a group of shapes is a single GroupObject -> whether you want to look inside the group is again a personal decision. The below returns a GroupObject as the active item as it is technically a single object.
- And etc...;)

Function:

```
Function GetActive()
    If typeof Selection Is Range Then 'ActiveCell can remain not nothing even if selection changes
        Set GetActive = ActiveCell
    ElseIf Not ActiveChart Is Nothing Then 'we test for ActiveChart instead of using typeof/typename as Selection could be e.g. ChartArea/PlotArea etc
        Set GetActive = ActiveChart
    ElseIf TypeName(Selection) = "DrawingObjects" Then
        'Multiple objects selected (e.g. embedded OLE objects / shapes / controls)
        'Container is DrawingObjects, whose ShapeRange contains the items
        Set GetActive = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
    Else
        'Single object selected (or else a special case not covered by DrawingObjects
        Set GetActive = Selection
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: @DavidZemens thanks for formatting. I don't know what happened - it went very weird when I added the bullets

Comment: I think it was the nested bullets and for some reason it wasn't recongnizing the line break before your code. Cheers.  BTW, same approach I would take with this question!!